# unserialize object export Excel blade view

Tags: laravel

I try to export a excel file from a blade view with an unserialize object from a text column in my database but i get an error .

Error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::transform()

Here is my controller :

```
 public function ExportExcel($id)
{
    $order = Order::find($id);

    $order->transform(function ($order , $key){

        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        return $order;

    });


    Excel::create('facture', function($excel) use ($order) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($order) {
            $sheet->loadView('cotisation_structure.factureExcelsingle')->with(['order' => $order]);
        });
    })->export('xls');

}
```

Here is my blade view :

```
<html> <body>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>N° Facture</th>
    <th>N° licence</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Type d'activité</th>
    <th>Saison</th>
    <th>Mode de paiement</th>
    <th>Montant</th>
    <th>Date Achat</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>{{$order->num_facture}}</td>
    <td>{{$order['item']->num_licence}}</td>
    <td>{{$order['item']->lb_nom}}</td>
    <td>{{$order['item']->lb_prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{$order['item']->activite_licencie->lb_activite}}</td>
    <td>{{$order['item']->saison->lb_saison}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->payment_method}}</td>
    <td>{{$order['price']}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->date_achat}}</td>
</tr>
```

It seems that Transform methode doesn't work for an object , only for a collection.

Comment: Instead of tranform just use `json_encode($order)`

Comment: thanks for your reply ! i get this error with json_encode($order) Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::json_encode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent find method return a single model instance Instead of returning a collection of models.

So transform method only working on collection not on single model instance.

Try this one

```
public function ExportExcel($id)
{
   $order = Order::find($id);
   $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);


   Excel::create('facture', function($excel) use ($order) {
     $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($order) {
         $sheet->loadView('cotisation_structure.factureExcelsingle')->with(['order' => $order]);
     });
   })->export('xls');

}
```

Note: Transform function working on collection not on a single object.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! now with your code i get this error : Undefined variable: item

Comment: there is problem with your structure can u debug the order result that what  it is actually returning in a result  and print out there. i need to check your structure that what it is actually returning

Comment: if your order have many item then please access it like below in your views

   <td>{{$order->item[0]->num_licence}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->item[0]->lb_nom}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->item[0]->lb_prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->item[0]->activite_licencie->lb_activite}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->item[0]->>saison->lb_saison}}</td>

Comment: here my table strucutre "id" => 7
    "created_at" => "2017-03-09 09:14:56"
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-09 09:14:56"
    "num_facture" => "F16171232"
    "structure_id" => 4
    "cart" => "O:8:"App\Cart":3:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:1;a:4:{s:3:"qty";i:1;s:7:"montant";s:6:"750.00";s:4:"item";O:13:"App\Licencies":24:{s:8:"\x00*\x00table";s:9:"licencies";s: ▶"
    "payment_method" => "Carte de Crédit"
    "date_achat" => "2017-03-09"     Has you can see in my "cart" table i have stored an item object ( serialzed) , i would like to to unserialize it and grab the info on it

Comment: you are accessing items property as a array on order obj instead of object property.

Comment: with {{$order->item[0]->lb_nom}} i get try to get property of non object

Comment: how i can access to items as an array ?

Comment: ok it's working i add this to my view @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)

Comment: your item object in in cart object so first you have to accept cart object then item obj like below 
{{$order->cart->item->lb_nom}}